# Moving all unknown and future folders to specific folder

Tags: c#

I am trying to create script for my terminal server, which will move all folders with their contents, created in the wrong place. I don't know which names these folders will have. As I noticed, moving folders in C# is a problem for some reason. Can someone help me with my code? It just deleting my test folders and nothing moves.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Programm
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string root = @"C:\Users\user1\Desktop";
            string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
            string destDirname = @"D:\confiscated";
            foreach (string path in subdirectoryEntries)
            {
                FileSystem.MoveDirectory(path, destDirname, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it:

```
string startPath = @"YOURSTARTPATH";
string endPath = @"YOURENDPATH";

foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(startPath))
{
    Directory.Move(directory, Path.Combine(endPath, Path.GetFileName(directory)));
}
```

This way, you will use the already provided by the framework classes to work with directories.

No need to include `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the main problem with the OP's code is that it doesn't add the directory name to the destination _root_ path causing the _contents_ of all the sub-folders in the source directory to be moved to the destination _root_ path. Using `Path.Combine` is what fixes the problem, not `Directory.Move`. In other words `FileSystem.MoveDirectory` should also work just fine if used with the correct path. That being said, the `System.IO` namespace is, of course, the standard way to deal with files and folders so I would go with `Directory.Move` too.

Comment: THX very much! Path.Combine + FileSystem.MoveDirectory worked fine!
Directory.Move not moving files and folders between disks.